# UIPageViewController behaving oddly on iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, ios8, uipageviewcontroller

It seems that after switching to Xcode 6 and the new iOS 8 SDK that my UIPageViewController is broken. Everything seems to work fine the first time I load the items into the UIPageViewController and display them but then when I transition to the next page programatically the subviews of the page view controller change size for some reason. Here is the code I'm using to set up the page view controller and transition:

```
 if (!self.coverViewController) {

    self.coverViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc]
            initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll
              navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal
                            options:nil];
    self.coverViewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll;
    self.coverViewController.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
    self.coverViewController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
  }
```

---

```
  NSArray* startingViewController = @[[self updatePageViewController:arc4random() % self.dataSource.numberOfItems]];
  [self.coverViewController setViewControllers:startingViewController direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
  [self.coverViewController.view setClipsToBounds:YES];
  [self updateFocusAndTrainingLabel];
  [self.coverViewController.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
  [self addChildViewController:self.coverViewController];
  [self.coverViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
  [self.view addSubview:self.coverViewController.view];
  NSDictionary* views = @{@"cover":self.coverViewController.view};
  [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[cover]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
  [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[cover]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
  [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

---

```
-(IBAction)pageForward:(id)sender {

  if (self.dataSource.numberOfItems > 1) {
    [self changePage:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward];
  }
}

- (void)changePage:(UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection)direction {

  int pageIndex = [self.coverViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]).pageIndex;

  if (direction == UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward) {
    pageIndex++;
  }
  else if (direction == UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse) {
    pageIndex = pageIndex - 1;
  }

  if (pageIndex < 0) {
    pageIndex = self.coverFlowPages.count - 1;
  } else if (pageIndex >= self.coverFlowPages.count) {
    pageIndex = 0;
  }
  UIViewController *viewController = [self updatePageViewController:pageIndex];
  if (viewController == nil) {
    return;
  }

  __weak typeof(self)weakSelf = self;
  self.nextItemButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
  self.previousItemButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
  [self.coverViewController setViewControllers:@[viewController]
                                     direction:direction
                                      animated:NO
                                    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
      if (finished) {
        weakSelf.nextItemButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;    
        weakSelf.previousItemButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [weakSelf updateLabels];
      }
  }];
}
```

Its strange because when you swipe horizontally to change pages it works fine its only when you use pageForward: does the view controller change height. The UIPageViewControllers height stays the same but I can see that the _QueueScrollView height changes after the transition.

Any help would be awesome! I've been looking at this problem for a while and can't figure anything out. Not sure if its an iOS 8 bug or something? Working perfectly fine on iOS 7

Comment: I am also have similar issue with UIPageViewController and UINavigationBar please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420396/adding-viewcontrollers-view-as-subview-to-uipageviewcontroller-in-ios-8-gives-w post and let me know if you have any suggestions. Thanks